# Which node to choose as a starting node for nearest neighbor algorithm

Tags: algorithm, nearest-neighbor, traveling-salesman, approximation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_algorithm

I'm using nearest neighbor algorithm to solve traveling salesman problem. It's extremely fast, but not accurate. I read somewhere about two improvements I could make. The first is instead of starting with one random point, run the nearest neighbor algorithm starting with each nodes. (So if there are N nodes, nearest neighbor is run N times) Then compare and choose the route with least total distance. This apear to be much much more precise. But it's too slow.

The other method is instead of randomly choosing the starting node, choose a special one. Then still run nearest neighbor just once to get the result. This won't be as accurate as the method above, but definitely much faster since the algorithm is run only once like before. But unfortunately I couldn't remember where I read that article and the criteria for choosing this starting node.

I'm guessing I should get total distance between each node to the other nodes, then the node that has the biggest value should be chosen as the starting node. (In my words, this is choosing a node that's "farthest away" from the graph, while also avoiding choosing node that's near the center of the graph) I think this way the route I get should be quite close to the optimal shortest route.

Am I thinking right?

Edit: I'm dealing with the metric TSP with Euclidean distance.

Comment: Are you using one of the [special cases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tsp#Special_cases) of TSP, or just a table of distances?

Comment: @MC Metric TSP with Euclidean distance..

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should probably just run the K-NN algorithm with a few starting nodes say O(log N), which would only cost O(K*N*log(N)). Pick the best tour and then use a tour improvement heuristic, either [2 opt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveling_salesman_problem#Iterative_improvement) or 2.5 opt with a limit on the number of moves or simply a time limit.

This should allow for the best balance of time vs accuracy, unless perhaps you start looking at [k-opt or v-opt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveling_salesman_problem#Iterative_improvement) based algorithms. Although, it doesn't sound like you've got the time for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can also cache every time you do a nearest neighbor. Even better if you do a K nearest neighbors. This is how it can work:

1. For each node find K nearest neighbors. Store it in cache.
2. Whenever you need to perform nearest neighbor, check cache first. Otherwise perform nearest neighbor and add it to the cache.